# textbox values not changes when paging in angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am using angular table for display my data. But i have a issues with it.
i entered values in first page. when i go to second page, first page values still display. how i fix this.
[my javascript file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNyep780KOpO7KS2qRJFEFwh_6mg7isW/view?usp=sharing)
Please check below screen to understand my issue.
[image]

[image]

```js
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:3}, {dataset:listOnhireContainers});
```

```html
<table ng-table="tableParams" 
       class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped table-scroll">
       <tbody style="width: 100%">
       <tr ng-repeat="SelectedContainer in $data track by $index">
        <td data-title="'Container No.'" ng-model="SelectedContainer.containerNo"
         class="row-center"> {{SelectedContainer.containerNo}}</td>
         
        
<td data-title="'9 AM'" class="row-center form-group">
 <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
           id=""           
           ng-change="ChangetoValAmFillRows(SelectedContaineraM[$index],$index,SelectedContainercheckDAM[$index])"
           ng-pattern="/^(0|[+-][1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?$/"
           ng-pattern-err-type="tempPattern"
           ng-model="SelectedContaineraM[$index]"  ng-readonly="truefalseAM[$index]"
           ng-disabled="(SelectedContainercheckDAM[$index] | uppercase) == '-' || (SelectedContainercheckDAM[$index] | uppercase) == 'OFF'   " />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
          
         
          <select name="addSymbol" style="width: initial" id="chkD"
                  ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in tempdrop.split(',')"
            ng-model="SelectedContainercheckDAM[$index]" ng-disabled="truefalseDAM[$index]"  class="form-control"
            ng-change="tempdropchangeAM($index); SetcheckDAMTempSelected(SelectedContainercheckDAM[$index],$index,SelectedContaineraM[$index]);">
               <option value="">--Select--</option>
           </select>
          </div>


         </div> 
</td>

<td data-title="'4 PM'" class="row-center form-group">
<div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control"
           id="selected-container-tempt"           
           ng-change="ChangetoValPmFillRows(SelectedContainerpM[$index],$index,SelectedContainercheckDPM[$index])"
           ng-pattern="/^(0|[+-][1-9])\d*(\.\d+)?$/"
           ng-pattern-err-type="tempPattern"
           ng-model="SelectedContainerpM[$index]" ng-readonly="truefalsePM[$index]" 
           ng-disabled="(SelectedContainercheckDPM[$index] | uppercase) == '-' || (SelectedContainercheckDPM[$index]  | uppercase) == 'OFF'  " />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
           <select name="addSymbol" style="width: initial" id="chkD"
            ng-options="choice as choice for (idx, choice) in tempdrop.split(',')"
            ng-model="SelectedContainercheckDPM[$index]" ng-disabled="truefalseDPM[$index]" class="form-control"
            ng-change="tempdropchangePM($index); SetcheckDPMTempSelected(SelectedContainercheckDPM[$index],$index,SelectedContainerpM[$index]);">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
           </select>
          </div>


         </div> 
</td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Are you able to provide the rest of your code? What you have provided is only the `html` for the table, which isn't really enough to help you.

Comment: hi peter, i can send javascript file that i use for this

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KNyep780KOpO7KS2qRJFEFwh_6mg7isW/view?usp=sharing this is my .js file

Comment: It isn't obvious where you are trying to do any kind of paging, which is the question you are asking. All the code you have provided is related to the table-display, and not to the paging. Essentially, when you change pages, you need to refresh the table content (regardless of whether the paging is done on the client or the server) - what you probably need is a `watch()`. I am guessing that the paging element is not connected in any way to the table-data, and that is your problem.